# Building new JSON with JQ and bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am trying to create JSON from scratch using bash.

The final structure needs to be like:

```
{
  "hosts": {
    "a_hostname" : {
      "ips" : [
          1,
          2,
          3
      ]
    },
    {...}
  }
}
```

---

First I'm creating an input file with the format:

```
hostname ["1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2"]
host-name2 ["3.3.3.3","4.4.4.4"]
```

This is being created by:

```
for host in $( ansible -i hosts all --list-hosts ) ; \
    do echo -n "${host} " ; \
    ansible -i hosts $host -m setup | sed '1c {' | jq -r -c '.ansible_facts.ansible_all_ipv4_addresses' ; \
done > hosts.txt
```

The key point here is that the IP list/array, is coming from a JSON file and being extracted by jq. This extraction outputs an already valid / quoted JSON array, but as a string in a txt file.

Next I'm using jq to parse the whole text file into the desired JSON:

```
jq -Rn '
    { "hosts": [inputs |
        split("\\s+"; "g") |
        select(length > 0 and .[0] != "") |
        {(.[0]):
            {ips:.[1]}
        }
    ] | add }
' < ~/hosts.txt
```

This is almost correct, everything except for the IPs value which is treated as a string and quoted leading to:

```
{
    "hosts": {
        "hostname1": {
            "ips": "[\"1.1.1.1\",\"2.2.2.2\"]"
        },
        "host-name2": {
            "ips": "[\"3.3.3.3\",\"4.4.4.4\"]"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm now stuck at this final hurdle - how to insert the IPs without causing them to be quoted again.

---

**Edit** - quoting solved by using `{ips: .[1] | fromjson }}` instead of `{ips:.[1]}`. 
However this was completely negated by @CharlesDuffy's help [suggesting converting to TSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917660/building-new-json-with-jq-and-bash?noredirect=1#comment88855054_50917660).

---

---

### Original Q body:

So far I've got to

```
jq -n {hosts:{}} | \
for host in $( ansible -i hosts all --list-hosts ) ; \
    do jq ".hosts += {$host:{}}" | \
    jq ".hosts.$host += {ips:[1,2,3]}" ; \
done ;
```

(`[1,2,3]` is actually coming from a subshell but including it seemed unnecessary as that part works, and made it harder to read)

This sort of works, but there seems to be 2 problems.

1) Final output only has a single host in it containg data from the first host in the list (this persists even if the second problem is bypassed):

```
{
  "hosts": {
    "host_1": {
      "ips": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

2) One of the hostnames has a `-` in it, which causes syntax and compiler errors from jq. I'm stuck going around quote hell trying to get it to be interpreted but also quoted. Help!

Thanks for any input.

Comment: It'd actually be helpful to know how you're getting your code -- if it's `$(...)` running the subshell to generate the jq code, f/e, that's generally a problematic practice.

Comment: Also, if we're going to narrow this down to only one `jq` process (not one-per-loop, but just one), we **really need** to feed the IPs in via the same stream as the hostnames, which means those inputs can't be punted on.

Comment: ...note how in my answer, I'm using `jq -R` to tell `jq` to read raw strings, not JSON, as input -- that way there's no need to try to escape your input into valid JSON, so dashes aren't special. Using `jq --arg foo "$foo"`, and then using `$foo` as a literal inside your `jq` expression, is another way to get literal strings in without any JSON step prior.

Comment: Why are you feeding the IPs as JSON, not plain text as my answer shows?

Comment: BTW, someone who doesn't have a multi-host ansible install can't test their answers, because they can't run `ansible -i hosts all <anything>`. Keeping your scope narrow and specifying literal inputs would help.

Comment: Also, don't use `echo -n`. It's specified by POSIX to produce unspecified output (which is better than `echo -e`, at least, which is outright illegal -- `-n` is the only exception to a black-letter "implementations shall support no options" rule). See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html, particularly APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections, suggesting `printf` be used instead.

Comment: Anyhow, make it `jq -r '.ansible_facts.ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | @tsv'` to separate your IP addresses with whitespace (the input format I directed you to use in the first place).

Comment: Also, note that we ask that questions be written for readability for someone seeing them for the first time. This means that if you're going to edit it, you should generally try to generate a single question that reads clearly front-to-back; anyone interested in the edit history can read it as a diff. (Edits that invalidate existing answers are indeed bad form, but that could have been handled in a way that doesn't involve changing the question at all; ie. a second question, "I know how to generate input format X, but I was asked for input format Y; how can I do that?")

Comment: ...btw, it'd be more efficient to just pipe a single stream of `ansible -m setup` documents into your single instance of `jq`. That way you don't have any other jq invocations in a loop at all. (To be clear, invoking external commands is one of the slowest things you can do in shell; no matter how fast that command is once it's started, processes need to be `fork()`ed off, and then the `execve()` to load their binaries pulls in all the linker/loader infrastructure -- so it's preferable to have fewer invocations that do more, rather than calling them in a loop).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - As a broad statement I'd say mistakes are all down to lack of experiance / knowledge rather than being awkward... I also can't thnak you enough for all the time you've put into helping with this and patience with me!

Comment: The IPs were JSON rather than plain as your answer suggested as I didn't know how to convert them. I am now happily dealing with TSV, and have replaced the echo with `printf "%s\t" ${host}` and `printf "\n"` respectively. This means your answer now works perfectly, with the slight mod to store them in a named key `{(.[0]): {ips: .[1:]} }`

Comment: Took me a while but I finally got it down to a single jq instance:
 `for host in $( ansible -i hosts all --list-hosts ) ; do ansible -i hosts $host -m setup 2>/dev/null | sed '1c {' ; done | jq -s ' { hosts: [ .[] | { ( .ansible_facts.ansible_hostname ) : { ips: .ansible_facts.ansible_all_ipv4_addresses  } } ] | add }'`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your input format is:

```
host_1 1 2 3
host_2 2 3 4
host-with-dashes 3 4 5
host-with-no-addresses
```

<sub>...re: edit specifying a different format: Add `@tsv` onto the JQ command producing the existing format to generate this one instead.</sub>

If you want to transform that to the format in question, it might look like:

```
jq -Rn '
{ "hosts": [inputs |
            split("\\s+"; "g") |
            select(length > 0 and .[0] != "") |
            {(.[0]): .[1:]}
           ] | add
}' <input.txt
```

Which yields as output:

```
{
  "hosts": {
    "host_1": [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3"
    ],
    "host_2": [
      "2",
      "3",
      "4"
    ],
    "host-with-dashes": [
      "3",
      "4",
      "5"
    ],
    "host-with-no-addresses": []
  }
}
```